# Unable to build / test a .NET Core test project on Azure DevOps - invalid langversion

Tags: testing, azure-devops

I'm trying to run a `dotnet test` in Azure DevOps but I keep getting this error:

> ControllerTests/v1Tests/FooTests/DetailsAsyncTests.cs(241,64): error CS8107: Feature 'default literal' is not available in C# 7.0. Please use language version 7.1 or greater.

This is the start of my `.csproj` file..

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
    <LangVersion>7.3</LangVersion>
    <PackageId><snipped></PackageId>
    <Version>0.0.0</Version>
  </PropertyGroup>

...
```

and this is the start of my `.yml` file..

```
name: $(Year:yyyy).$(Month).$(DayOfMonth).$(Rev:r)
pool:
  vmImage: 'Ubuntu 16.04'

variables:
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'
....

steps

<snip>

- script: |
    dotnet test tests/snip/foo1.csproj --configuration $(buildConfiguration) -p:Version=$(Build.BuildNumber)
    dotnet test tests/snip/foo2.csproj --configuration $(buildConfiguration) -p:Version=$(Build.BuildNumber)
    dotnet test tests/snip/foo3.csproj --configuration $(buildConfiguration) -p:Version=$(Build.BuildNumber)
  displayName: 'dotnet test'

...
```

I've also tried `<LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>` in the `.csproj`.

I've triple-checked that the project file is has that `<LangVersion>` in it, where the test is getting tested.

---

### Update

So I seem to have it possibly working, but I still don't know if this is a 'hack' solution or the proper solution. However, I'm still unsure *why* this problem is happening.

I added `langver` as an msbuild property:

```
dotnet test tests/snip/foo2.csproj 
    --configuration $(buildConfiguration) 
    -p:Version=$(Build.BuildNumber)
    -p:langversion=latest
```

Notice the last param ...

Answer (score 0):

> i'm unsure WHY this problem is happening ... so I would love some help explaining that

There is a situation that can cause this issue, but I am not quite sure if it applies to you, you can check it out.

When we set the property `<LangVersion>7.3</LangVersion>` in the project file, which was in the `debug` property group:

[image]

**But** when we build it in the Azure Devops, we set build configuration to `release`, in your `.yml` file:

```
variables:
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'
....
```

This may be reason why you need to pass the parameters again (`-p:langversion=latest`) when you build with Azure Devops.

Besides, the easiest way to do it for all project configurations(personal):

- Right-click `YourProject`, click `Properties`
- Click `Build` if it's not already selected
- Change Configuration to `All Configurations`
- Click `Advanced`...
- Change the language version

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi @leo - what's interesting with your suggestion above is that the `.csproj` file has _nothing_ to do with `DEBUG` or `RELEASE`. it's just a file, regardless of the 'Configuration'. Usually, the `csproj` has specific lines in it that say (pseduo code) `if configuration == debug, then do this .. or include this nuget, etc`. There is no msbuild `if checks` in the sample file, above. So I don't think your answer is accurate?

Comment: Also, I tried the `All Configurations -> Advanced` thing before I posted this question - still didn't work :(